# A convex quadrilateral with propotion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Let P be the intersection of the convex quadrilateral ABCD. Let X,Y,Z be points on AB,BC,CD respectively such that $\frac{AX}{XB}=\frac{BY}{YC}=\frac{CZ}{ZD}=2$. Suppose that XY is tangent to the circumcircle of triangle CYZ and YZ is tangent to the circumcircle of triangle BXY. Prove that $\angle APD=\angle XYZ$

[image]
I did not make progress except for proving that $\Delta BXY\sim \Delta CYZ$, using alternate segment theorem.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you proved that $\Delta BXY\sim \Delta CYZ$ then $$\frac{BX}{CY}=\frac{BY}{CZ}$$ or
$$\frac{\frac{1}{3}AB}{\frac{1}{3}BC}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}BC}{\frac{2}{3}DC}$$ or
$$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{BC}{DC},$$ which says 
$$\Delta ABC\sim\Delta BCD.$$
Id est, $$\measuredangle APD=\measuredangle BDC+\measuredangle PCD=\measuredangle ACB+\measuredangle BCD-\measuredangle ACB=\measuredangle BCD=\measuredangle XYZ.$$

Comment: Beautiful answer! I can't believe I did not see ABC  is similar to BCD.